# Using a cartesian product in LINQ and Entity framework to combine 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

before I return "set.select" I would like to include fields from another table but I canot join this table because it has no fields in common with the other two tables. How may I adjust my code below to achieve this? Iam using vs2012 sql and in MVC c#

```
var set = 
    (from m in managers
     from t in context.tblCompany
     join tsc in context.tblStyling on t.ccID equals tsc.ccID
     select new { tsc.ccID,LogoIcon = tsc.Icon , tsc.style1, tsc.style2, t.Desc })
    .ToList();

return set.Select(c => new Settings(c.ccID, c.style1, c.style2, c.Desc, c.LogoIcon , m.firstName , m.lastName));
```

Comment: Paste the code of the classes, explaining what you want to achieve.

Comment: What's the idea behind this query? I can't imagine a a useful case for a Cartesian product between managers and companies.

Comment: And why do you [ask twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30394446/861716)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it looks like you want to join `context.tblCompany` and `context.tblStyle` and get the cross product of the resulting set and `managers`.  If that is correct, then you are already there.  You just need to include the fields from `manager` that you want in your select statement:

```
var set = 
    (from m in managers
     from t in context.tblCompany 
     join tsc in context.tblStyling on t.ccID equals tsc.ccID
     select new 
        { 
            tsc.ccID, 
            LogoIcon = tsc.Icon, 
            tsc.style1, 
            tsc.style2, 
            t.Desc, 
            m.firstName, 
            m.lastName })
    .ToList();

return set;
```